# Update and Append Rows based on Two Criteria in VBA Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Could anyone help me write a code in VBA that updates a table, or appends new data based on criteria in two columns?

For example, there might be a name column, and a project column, and we want to check if Mark worked on project1. If Mark did work on project1, then update his row with new data from a separate spreadsheet. If Mark worked on project2 in the separate spreadsheet, but that is not documented in the original spreadsheet, append Mark and project2, along with the information from that row. If Betty worked on project1, and the original spreadsheet has this information, update this row. If Betty worked on project2, but the original spreadsheet does not have this information, append it as a new row. So the names AND projects will both appear multiple times in the table, just with different combinations.

So the idea is to check both columns at the same time, and update and append new data accordingly.

Here's the faulty code I have now:

```
Dim filename As String
Dim ManagerLEs As Workbook
Dim ProjectLEs As Workbook
Set ProjectLEs = ThisWorkbook

filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If filename = Empty Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ManagerLEs = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)

Dim first_blank_row As Long
first_blank_row = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row
starting_row = 4

Dim r As Long

r = starting_row

Dim namefound As Range
Dim projectfound As Range

firstname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
projectname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & r).Value

Do While firstname <> 0

Set namefound = Columns("a:a").Find(what:=firstname, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set projectfound = Columns("d:d").Find(what:=projectname, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    'look for current ticket number in main file
    If (namefound Is Nothing And projectfound Is Nothing) Then

        'add info to end of main file
        For c = 1 To 57
        ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Cells(first_blank_row, c) = ManagerLEs.Worksheets("LEs").Cells(r, c)
        first_blank_row = first_blank_row + 1
        Next c
    Else

        'overwrite existing line of main file
        For c = 1 To 57
        ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Cells(namefound.Row, c) = ManagerLEs.Worksheets("LEs").Cells(r, c)
        Next c
    End If

        r = r + 1
        firstname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
        projectname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & r).Value
Loop
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try posting the code you have write now and where you're getting stuck. It's a lot easier to address a particular issue than a whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this type of requirement. It has many functions for transforming data, including Merge and Append. You build your Query in a visual UI by clicking buttons (it generates code) and can see the resulting data at every step.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-Help-2b433a85-ddfb-420b-9cda-fe0e60b82a94?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

Tried this code, doesn't work.

```
Sub importLEs()

With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim filename As String
Dim ManagerLEs As Workbook
Dim ProjectLEs As Workbook
Set ProjectLEs = ThisWorkbook

'open file that you are importing data from
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If filename = Empty Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ManagerLEs = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)

Dim first_blank_row As Long

first_blank_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
starting_row = 4

Dim r As Long
Dim rr As Long

r = starting_row
rr = 4

firstname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
projectname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & r).Value
mastername = ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Range("a" & rr).Value
masterproject = ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Range("d" & rr).Value

Do While firstname <> 0

    'counter to check if a row is updated
    flag = False

    Do While mastername <> 0

        If mastername = firstname And masterproject = projectname Then

            'update existing line of main file
            For c = 10 To 57
            ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Cells(rr, c) = ManagerLEs.Worksheets("LEs").Cells(r, c)
            Next c
            flag = True
            Exit Do

        End If

    Loop

        'if data does not exist, append data to the end of main file
        If flag = False Then

            For c = 1 To 57
            ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Cells(first_blank_row, c) = ManagerLEs.Worksheets("LEs").Cells(r, c)
            Next c

        End If

        first_blank_row = first_blank_row + 1
        rr = rr + 1
        r = r + 1
        firstname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
        projectname = ManagerLEs.ActiveSheet.Range("d" & r).Value
        mastername = ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Range("a" & rr).Value
        masterproject = ProjectLEs.Worksheets("Template").Range("d" & rr).Value

Loop

With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = Excel.xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Need a little more help.